# IISNode Socket.io NodeJS app (connect from c# using socketio4net)

Tags: node.js, iisnode, socket.io, socketio4net

I have simple nodejs server running using iisnode.

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

io.configure(function () {
    io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);
    if (process.env.IISNODE_VERSION) {
        io.set('resource', '/nodejs/socket.io');
    }
});

function handler(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("Node JS is Running");
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log('a socket is connected');
    });

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

I want to talk to this socket from c# code (not javascript). I was running the nodejs server without iisnode before and the following code worked.

```
Client socket = new Client("somelink");
            socket.Error += SocketError;
            socket.On("connect", (fn) =>
                {
                    socket.Emit("new_order", 301);
                });

            socket.Connect();
```

But now I am running the server using iisnode and I cannot connect using the same code. I had to change my javascript code to connect to the server too.

from : =>

```
var socket = io.connect('somelink');
```

to: =>

```
 var socket = io.connect('somelink', {resource: 'nodejs/socket.io'});
```

My question is how do I change my c# code to connect to the nodejs server running on iisnode.

```
Client socket = new Client("somelink/nodejs/socket.io");
```

doesn't work. (handshake error)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how the Socket.io C# client works. But one thing you may be able to do on the server side to make the iisnode-hosted version behave exactly the same as a self-hosted one is to create a dedicated Web Site for the application as opposed to hosting it in IIS virtual directory. That way you will not need to customize the `resource` parameter when hosting in iisnode.

Comment: I used your tutorial to make the nodejs app run with iisnode in IIS virtual directory. I am pretty new at this. How do i go about creating a dedicated website? Any tips would be appreciated.